How can the properties of constituent controls in a UserControl be made available for use in ApplicationSettings?
How can the properties of constituent controls in a VB Windows Forms UserControl be made available for use in ApplicationSettings?
I created a UserControl with a Textbox. I would like to make TextBox1.Text available for use with My.Settings via ApplicationSettings, but it does not appear in the list. I also created a property to wrap it, but that also does not appear in the list.
How do I do this?
In example and screenshot below, neither 'TextBox11' nor the user-defined property 'UserControlText' are found in the Application Settings list.
Am I forced to do it in code, such as: UserControl1.UserControlText = My.Settings.UserControlText?
Imports System.ComponentModel    
Public Class UserControl1    
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property UserControlText() As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            TextBox1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property    
End Class



You probably need to also add an event to notify of changes to that property, because the bound setting can't be updated without that. You may also need to apply the Bindable attribute.

In case you haven't though about it, you can override the Text Property of the UserControl (still returning / setting the Text property of the TextBox), decorating with <Browsable>, <EditorBrowsable> and <Localizable>. You probably don't need serialization support if this Property is just meant to bind to the ApplicationSettings, it should be automatically serialized according to the setting's value

Thank you both. I'm searching for better examples of user controls which include the update event and binding attribute. Perhaps could either of you point me to some good reading/examples for these?

@jmcilhinney is this the correct direction to go in? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

See the two paragraphs, Using Standard Events notifications and Using INotifyPropertyChanged in this Q&A. It describes the two most common patterns used to generate data-binding notifications. WinForms Controls, in general, implement the former, because the standard data binding mechanic expects that kind of behavior (so, there isn't much you need to do, just follow the pattern, the infrastructure takes care of the rest). In custom classes, an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is more common, because it simplifies the procedure

Here's a blog post of mine that explains how to implement your own events. As Jimi says, I'd go with an event per property, e.g. a SomePropertyChanged event raised by an OnSomePropertyChanged method to notify when a SomeProperty property changes. In your case you would, for example, handle the TextChanged event of your child TextBox and then raise your own event.

I just did a bit of testing and the issue seems to be that DesignerSerializationVisibility attribute. I added a similar property without that and it could be bound by default, even without an event. I added that attribute and it could no longer be bound. I added an event and a Bindable attribute and it still didn't work. I removed that attribute and it worked again. I re-added the attribute but with Visible instead of Content and it worked. Is there a specific reason you did it the way you did? Content doesn't seem a good choice for a String property.

Note that, even if you remove or change that attribute, you should still add the event. If there's no event, your bound setting won't be updated when the control property value changes.

Ok, that's a lot to absorb; I will study it all. Thank you for the testing you did. For the attribute, I was learning from the documentation, linked below. It does say the attribute is assumed for all UserControl members, and the default value is .Visible, so that explains what you found. There was another page, which I can't find now, where someone said .Visible doesn't do what you think and .Content should be used. This may have started my confusion.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN
